# Fancybox wont load after load function

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

OK here is the issue. I have tested the following script on a test page on my server and it works fine, but when I copy the script into my actual page, it wont run the after load function, just the basic fancybox. I cannot understand why. Here is the html I have used

In the head section....

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5
media="screen" />

<!-- Add Button helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox
buttons.css?v=1.0.5" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js
v=1.0.5"></script>

<!-- Add Thumbnail helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox
thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js
v=1.0.7"></script>

<!-- Add Media helper (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js
v=1.0.6"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
openEffect  : 'none',
closeEffect : 'none',
prevEffect : 'none',
nextEffect : 'none',
closeBtn  : false,
helpers : {
title : {
type : 'inside'
},
buttons : {}
},
afterLoad: function() {
this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? '
- ' + this.title : '');
}
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.fancybox-custom .fancybox-skin {
box-shadow: 0 0 50px #222;
}
</style>
```

Then as an example of the call within the  tags

```
<a class="fancybox-buttons" href="img/parts/billet-1.jpg" data-fancybox-
group="button" title="Lightech Mirror Block Off Plates"><img
src="img/parts/billet/thumbnail.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a class="fancybox-buttons" href="img/parts/billet/billet-2.jpg" data-fancybox
-group="button" title="Oberon Bar End Mirrors"></a>
```

If I place this code into a blank html page such as the test.html file I mentioned all works well. As it stands in my actual webpage it runds up to the afterload call then ignores the rest. I am stumped for ideas.

Comment: are you sure your paths are correct? browse the source code and click on the links to your scripts to make sure they are loaded from where you said they are

Comment: BTW, if the code above is an exact copy of what you have in your actual website, then you are missing some closing brackets `}); // the .ready() methos is not closed` in your script

Comment: OK I have found the problem. I was calling another jquery plugin on the page: (jquery1.8.3.js) as well as the one in the head section used by fancybox. When I took it out it works, trouble is the 1.8.3 js file is used solely to enable a javascript "Back to top" button, so is there a way to enable this and still not conflict with the jquery file that fancybox needs in the head section, as that file (jquery1.10.1.min.js) does not support the javascript for the back to top javascipt call that's made when you click on the "back to top" button? The code in the button is: javascript:moveToTop().

Comment: a single version of jQuery (ideally the latest) should be enough for most plugins. BTW jquery1.8.3.js is not a plugin, is the core script jQuery plugins rely on